# Is it possible to beacon with iOS in a background service?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Based on [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/turning_an_ios_device_into_an_ibeacon) documentation I understand that iOS devices can function as bluetooth beacons.

The documentation states that apps must be in the foreground for the beacon to work.

We need the beaconing to work when the app is not in the foreground. Could we solve this by using a service (similar to Android)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but **you simply cannot transmit standard beacon formats like iBeacon, AltBeacon or Eddystone when an app is in the background on iOS.**

Apple prohibits this because there is limited ability to advertise on bluetooth, and not all apps would be able to do this at the same time.  Instead, Apple uses a proprietary technique that allows background apps to advertise Bluetooth services in the background.  This proprietary technique is not compatible with the above bluetooth beacon transmission formats.

That said, a creative project has found a way to harness Apple's proprietary background advertising technique to allow you to use a *custom* beacon advertising format that does work in the background on iOS.  The main disadvantage is that support is limited to receiving the advertisement on other iOS devices.

The project that lets you do this is also called AltBeacon (but should not be confused with the open source AltBeacon format described above)  You can read more about it here: https://github.com/Decemberlabs/AltBeacon